# Como usar loops en python

Tags: python, bucles

Hola soy muy nuevo en la programación en general y en este foro también así que la verdad soy medio bobo y perdónenme si no formule bien mi pegunta etc...

Buenas tardes me gustaría saber si alguien me podría explicar como hacer loops en python como se usan que son todo en especial es a lo que me refiero no se nada de ellos mas que que son es un tema que no e entendido bien

Bueno también pasare el código del programa que quiero hacer loop por si alguien cuenta con el tiempo me explique como implementar el loop en mi programa de python

```
¨print("Calculadora")
print(" ")
print("Si quieres hacer")
print("Una suma escriba sum")
print("Una resta escriba res")
print("Una multiplicacion escriba mut")
print("Una division escriba div")
txt1 = input("Ingresa aqui el numero de el problema matematico que quieras hacer: ")
print(" ")



if(txt1=="sum"):
    sum1 = input("Dime de cuantos digitos quieres hacer tu problema matematico el minimo de numeros es 2 y el maximo es 5: ")
    if(sum1=="2"):
        sum2 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        sum3 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        print( int(sum2) + int(sum3) )
    
    if(sum1=="3"):
        sum4 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        sum5 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        sum6 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        print( int(sum4) + int(sum5) + int(sum6) )

    if(sum1=="4"):
        sum7 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        sum8 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        sum9 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        sum10 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(sum7) + int(sum8) + int(sum9) + int(sum10) )

    if(sum1=="5"):
        sum11 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        sum12 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        sum13 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        sum14 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        sum15 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(sum11) + int(sum12) + int(sum13) + int(sum14) + int(sum15) )



if(txt1=="res"):
    res1 = input("Dime de cuantos digitos quieres hacer tu problema matematico el minimo de numeros es 2 y el maximo es 5: ")
    if(res1=="2"):
        res2 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        res3 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        print( int(res2) - int(res3) )
    
    if(res1=="3"):
        res4 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        res5 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        res6 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        print( int(res4) - int(res5) - int(res6) )

    if(res1=="4"):
        res7 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        res8 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        res9 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        res10 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(res7) - int(res8) - int(res9) - int(res10) )

    if(res1=="5"):
        res11 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        res12 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        res13 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        res14 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        res15 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(res11) - int(res12) - int(res13) - int(res14) - int(res15) )



if(txt1=="mut"):
    mut1 = input("Dime de cuantos digitos quieres hacer tu problema matematico el minimo de numeros es 2 y el maximo es 5: ")
    if(mut1=="2"):
        mut2 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        mut3 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        print( int(mut2) * int(mut3) )
    
    if(mut1=="3"):
        mut4 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        mut5 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        mut6 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        print( int(mut4) * int(mut5) * int(mut6) )

    if(mut1=="4"):
        mut7 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        mut8 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        mut9 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        mut10 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(mut7) * int(mut8) * int(mut9) * int(mut10) )

    if(mut1=="5"):
        mut11 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        mut12 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        mut13 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        mut14 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        mut15 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(mut11) * int(mut12) * int(mut13) * int(mut14) * int(mut15) )



if(txt1=="div"):
    div1 = input("Dime de cuantos digitos quieres hacer tu problema matematico el minimo de numeros es 2 y el maximo es 5: ")
    if(div1=="2"):
        div2 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        div3 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        print( int(div2) / int(div3) )
    
    if(div1=="3"):
        div4 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        div5 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        div6 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        print( int(res4) / int(res5) / int(res6) )

    if(div1=="4"):
        div7 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        div8 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        div9 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        div10 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(div7) / int(div8) / int(div9) / int(div10) )

    if(div1=="5"):
        div11 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        div12 = input("Dame tu segundo numero: ")
        div13 = input("Dame tu tercer numero: ")
        div14 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        div15 = input("Dame tu primer numero: ")
        print( int(div11) / int(div12) / int(div13) / int(div14) / int(div15) )


print("Final del programa si quieres hacer otro problema reinicia el programa")
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con como hacer loops? que es exactamente lo que no entendes? asi como esta, la pregunta no tiene respuesta porque no suena logica. Para que es todo ese codigo? Sabes que es un loop? buscate iteraciones? buscate que hace la instruccion for, o while?

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario ahora mismo analizo mi prgunta y la modifico

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te dejo como sería tu código si se usasen bucles

```
print("Calculadora\n")
print("Si quieres hacer")
print("Una suma escriba sum")
print("Una resta escriba res")
print("Una multiplicacion escriba mut")
print("Una division escriba div")
entrada = input("Ingresa aqui el problema matematico que quieras hacer: ")
cantidad = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de valores que quieres operar: "))

valores = []
for i in range(cantidad):
    valor = float(input(f"Dime el valor {i}: "))
    valores.append(valor)

resultado = 0

if entrada == "sum":
    for valor in valores:
        resultado += valor
if entrada == "res":
    for valor in valores:
        resultado -= valor
if entrada == "mut":
    for valor in valores:
        resultado *= valor
if entrada == "div":
    for valor in valores:
        resultado /= valor

print(f"Tu resultado es {resultado}")
print("Final del programa si quieres hacer otro problema reinicia el programa")
```

Comment: omg amigo como le hiciste para un código gigante redactarlo a nada es mucho pedir pero conoces un buen curso de python se apenas lo muy básico muchas gracias por responder mi pregunta :3

Comment: @tamalitos Yo no aprendí python haciendo cursos asi que no sabría recomendarte ninguno, la manera en la que yo aprendí fue mediante foros y ejercicios, por ejemplo en esta página https://aprendeconalf.es/docencia/python/ejercicios/ puedes encontrar ejercicios desde lo más básico hasta lo mas avanzado y mediante esta presentación completa https://aprendeconalf.es/manual-python/ puedes aclararte todas las dudas que tengas, espero haber servido de ayuda.

Comment: @tamalitos, hay páginas web muy buenas que tienen muchos cursos de programación, te paso algunas: Coursera, FreeCodeCamp, Khan Academy, edX, Udacity, Píldoras Informáticas..y el mejor de todos, YouTube, y Google. Y claro que StackOverflow también. Saludos, y buena suerte!